# Based on experience, what cannot be automated and is best to still test manually?

Tags: automated-testing, qa-role

- Which tasks cannot be automated and are best to be tested in a manual way?

Comment: Voting to close this question as opinion-based since there is no proper answer on what will be in future.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an interview question, but is definitely opinion-based.

Comment: I like to say build it in such a way that it can be automatically tested or not build it at all, as manual testing will just slow you down and makes it harder to restructure the code for adaptability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the future of QA testing and which roles will be most important?**

- The future of QA testing will involve more and more browser based testing, as many software service choose browser as their platform.
- QA testing on mobile device will receive more attention too.
- In terms of testing technique, QA has developed a number of mature ways to come up with tests on a higher abstract level, e.g. BDD; I personally do not think there will be any major development in this area.
- I personally think, more effort will be spent on evaluating existing automated test cases' effectiveness, e.g. who is guarding the guards? [mutation testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing)

**Which tasks cannot be automated and must be tested in a manual way?**

- Tasks that are repetitive in nature are the best candidates to be automated
- Tasks that involve random factors (e.g. cannot be predicated) cannot be automated effectively, hence manual testing is always required.
- Tasks that demand too much overhead to be automated will need manual testing too, e.g. a software feature that needs a fast smoke testing before it is shipped to customer this afternoon.